# Custom CSS and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, theming

How to add custom css and javascript file in Drupal 8.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! As it, the question is too broad, and the answers would just copy-paste what the documentation on drupal.org says. If you have a specific issue, then ask about that.

Answer (score 1):

there are several ways to add js/css, one example:

**Attaching custom javascript or css in your theme**

Add a library to yourtheme.libraries.yml in your theme folder:

```
  yourlib:
  version: 2.6
  css:
    theme:
      css/your.css: {}
  js:
    js/your.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

The paths given are relative to your theme. Dependencies is optional, you can force loading of additional js like jquery.

Now to add this library to your theme go to yourtheme.info.yml and add it like this:

```
    libraries:
      - yourtheme/yourlib
```

Comment: I am using theme business therefore I have added
custom-styling:
  version: 2.6
  css:
    theme:
      css/my.css: {}
  js:
    js/my.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
in file business.libraries.yml
and added
libraries:
  - business/custom-styling
in business.info.yml
After that business folder there is css folder in which I added my.css
But its not working. Could you please help?

Comment: Would you be able to update your question with this information/code?

Comment: How to add custom css and javascript file in Drupal 8.

I am using theme business therefore I have added 
custom-styling: 
version: 2.6 css: 
theme: css/my.css: {} 
js: js/my.js: {} 
dependencies: - core/jquery in file business.libraries.yml
and added 
libraries: 
- business/custom-styling 
in business.info.yml
After that business folder there is css folder in which I added my.css But its not working. 
Could you please help?

Comment: could you please give another way to add custom.css file ?

Comment: @TanmayKadam Your question, insofar as it can be understood, has already been answered - if you have a new question, please ask it separately. This is a Q+A site, not support forum, we won't provide a debugging session in the comments here. If you want to increase the chances of getting an answer, then provide a higher quality, more detailed question. Thanks